# error when implementing eccjs library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement this `ecc` library of NodeJS,
https://github.com/jpillora/eccjs.

The file that I am trying to run is,

```
https://github.com/jpillora/eccjs/blob/gh-pages/examples/simple.js
```

The problem is, when I try to run the file using `node simple.js` command, I get the following error,

```
eccjs-gh-pages/examples/simple.js:31
var keys = ecc.generate(ecc.ENC_DEC);
               ^
TypeError: Object function ecc() {
  return new ECC();
} has no method 'generate'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Project/eccjs-gh-pages/examples/simple.js:31:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

However, when I run the same file using an html file (https://github.com/jpillora/eccjs/blob/gh-pages/index.html) as follows,

```
  <script src="examples/simple.js"></script>
```

I can see the output of in my Chrome console.

Can someone please tell me why the file is not working using command line but working fine when executed through the browser ? and is there anyway to do so ?

**Edit:**
I have already commented out the following line,

```
var ecc = require('../dist/0.1/ecc');
```

in example.js before running it in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there is no `generate` method in `https://github.com/jpillora/eccjs/blob/gh-pages/dist/0.1/ecc.js` while there is one in `https://github.com/jpillora/eccjs/blob/gh-pages/dist/0.3/ecc.js`

replacing,

```
var ecc = require('../dist/0.1/ecc');
```

with,

```
var ecc = require('../dist/0.3/ecc');
```

should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `generate` method from where its coming from in the js file.

Add an import statement to the to of the file pointing to the module supporting this generate method.

Looking at the file, this is currently commented out:

```
// var ecc = require('../dist/0.1/ecc');
```

Try un-commenting it.

Note, this has to be commented when used in HTML as a JS file.

**Edit**
Just saw your changes. Maybe you're using an outdated ecc module. As the error states there is no `generate` method in the ecc file.

Alternatively, install the latest ecc via npm using `npm install eccjs` and replacement `var ecc = require('../dist/0.1/ecc');` with `var ecc = require('eccjs');`

Answer (score 0):

add

```
var ecc = require('eccjs');
```

and `npm install eccjs`

then try to run

this means eccjs module is published in npm repository and seems like if we require that module `generate` method is available.